# Unable to find the right code to combine two queries to retrieve from firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to display a list of restaurants by using RecyclerView which are open morning at 6am to 12pm, now I am not able to combine my two queries of child nodes(open, close) values to display the restaurant which are open at that time gap, I am looking for a way to combine the 2 queries

[image: My database]

[image: this is my code part of adding all restaurants]

Comment: What should we do with **images of code**?

Comment: Post your code in text, not image. So that it can be easier for us to read and to re-use in our answers.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `Firebase Realtime` database does not support queries on multiple properties, supports only queries on a single child property. So to solve that, you'll need to create an extra field to keep both fields. So to achieve this, you need to create a new prpoerty which in your database should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- BBQ Nation
          |
          --- BBQ Nation
               |
               --- Open: 12
               |
               --- Close: 16
               |
               --- Open_Close: 12_16
               |
               --- //The other details
```

So as you can see, the `Open_Close` property combines the values that you want to filter on.

Unlike Firebase Realtime database, [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) allows [compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries). You should take a look at this. So a query as the one below is allowed in Cloud Firestore without creating a combined property.

```
itemIdRef.whereEqualTo("Open", 12).whereEqualTo("Close", 16);
```